# VSTO Outlook: Custom task pane height includes the titlebar or not?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

When I set the [height](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.height?view=vsto-2017) of the custom task pane (which is in points), this height includes the titlebar or not? Microsoft does not tell anything about it, I doubt if the height refers only to the content, I mean, the user control, or also it takes into account the custom task pane title bar. Could someone confirm this, please?

For example, if I set the height to 80 points, does it includes the titlebar? or not (only the user control height)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `Size` (`Height` or `Width`) of custom task panes includes the title bar. This is for the whole task pane.

If you need to know the client area you may check out the `Size` property of the user control placed there.

Comment: Ok,thanks for confirming it. My problem was that I needed to set the height of the custom task pane, only its content - without taken into account the title bar - to 48 points so when I initially set it using ctp.Height I don't know which value to assign to it (48 + ?), I don't know what it is the height of only the title bar.

Comment: Try to set the height to a lower value and then check the results, following that way you will find the answer.